# Definition of $0$ as given in G.B. Fine's book, "The Number System Of Algebra".

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

I am reading G.B. Fine's book, ["The Number System Of Algebra"](https://archive.org/details/thenumbersystemo17920gut). He defines the number $a-b$ as the solution of the equation $a=x+b$, or the number satisfying the equation $(a-b)+b=a$.

In article 13 he claims that $a-a$ has value which is independent of the value of $a$ and acts as an additive identity. He proves it as,

$(a-a)+(a+b)=(((a-a)+a)+b)$

by definition $((a-a)+a)$ is $a$. So the above written equation becomes,

$(a-a)+(a+b)=(a+b)$

Now, $(b-b)+(a+b)=(((b-b)+b)+a)))=b+a=a+b$

So we see that any number of form $a-a$ is altogether independent of $a$ and may properly be represented by a symbol unrelated to $a$. The symbol which has been chosen for it is $0$.

> - The problem is that how can we show that the quantity $(a-a)+s$ is equal to the quantity $(b-b)+s$, i.e. both the quantiteis are independnt of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: They've both been shown to be equal to $a-b$, and things that are equal to the same thing are equal to each other.

Comment: @MJD I am not able to understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just overlooked the article. It is easy to prove that $a-a=b-b$. It is due to the axiom-VII:

If $$\begin{cases}
      \text{If}\ \ a+c=b+c \\ 
      \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  a=b
\end{cases}$$

We have $$(a−a)+(a+b)=(b-b)+(a+b)$$
So, $(a-a)=(b-b)$